# adding several columns below another in a table in R

Tags: r

I'm quite a beginner in R and I'm wondering whether it is possible to add multiple columns within a table/tibble below another?

My example:

```
my_tibble <- tibble(a = c(1:4),
                    b = c(2:5), 
                    c = c(3:6), 
                    d = c(4:7), 
                    a1 = c(4:1),
                    b2 = c(5:2), 
                    c2 = c(6:3),
                    d2 = c(7:4))
```

In the end, I'd like to look it like this:

```
my_tibble_1 <- tibble(a = c(1,2,3,4,2,3,4,5,3,4,5,6,4,5,6,7),
                      a1 = c(4,3,2,1,5,4,3,2,6,5,4,3,7,6,5,4))
```

Is it possible to do this in R / the tidyverse?

Thanks a lot !!

Comment: Not clear about the pattern to combine the columns together

Comment: @d.b Why not use `Reduce`?  It is naturally suited for this task, and you avoid several layers of operations.

Answer (score 0):

I might have misunderstood your question, but I will try to answer. You need to provide a list of columns according to your desired order:

```
my_order <- c("a", "a1")
my_tibble[ ,my_order]
```

If you want to combine columns 1 through 4 and 5 to 8 into two new columns:

```
nc <- ncol(my_tibble)
my_new_df <- data.frame(a = Reduce(`c`, my_tibble[, 1:(nc/2)]),
           a1 = Reduce(`c`, my_tibble[, (nc/2+1):nc]))
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is to select columns of same name

```
library(dplyr)
my_tibble %>%
     select(starts_with('a'))
```

---

Or if we are interested in combining the 1st 4 columns as a single column, next 4 as 2nd, then use `split`, and convert it to a `data.frame`

```
out <- data.frame(lapply(split.default(my_tibble, rep(c('a', 'a1'), 
           each = 4)), unlist))
row.names(out) <- NULL

out
#   a a1
#1  1  4
#2  2  3
#3  3  2
#4  4  1
#5  2  5
#6  3  4
#7  4  3
#8  5  2
#9  3  6
#10 4  5
#11 5  4
#12 6  3
#13 4  7
#14 5  6
#15 6  5
#16 7  4
```

---

If it is based on the occurrence of 'a' as the prefix in column name

```
grp <- cumsum(startsWith(names(my_tibble), 'a'))
data.frame(lapply(split.default(my_tibble, grp), unlist))
```